# signal to stop script in python

Tags: python, signals

i am trying out signals for the first time with python and i created some basic script that just cant seem to get it right. Can somebody explain where im making the mistake?

```
import signal
import sys


def signal_abort_script(signal, frame):
    """
    Signal handler function to catch KeyboardInterrupt (Ctrl+C) and exit the script gracefully.
    """
    sys.exit()


def main():
    # Set up the signal handler to catch KeyboardInterrupt (Ctrl+C)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_abort_script)

    # print not stopped forever
    while True:
        print("not stopped forever")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What is your goal and what behavior are you getting that is not what you want?

Comment: what im actually trying to achieve is that i want this to run and wherever i click ctrl+c (also for example when im watching youtube on my second monitor) it should stop my script

Comment: there's a potential naming conflict that might be causing your issue. You've named your custom signal handler function signal_abort_script, which could conflict with the signal module you're importing. Here's a modified version of your code to avoid this potential issue.

Comment: @Malludeveloper Why would that conflict with anything? Everything imported will be named `signal.something`, because they didn't use `from signal import *`

Comment: Your script works fine for me. I added `time.sleep(1)` to the loop so it won't flood my screen.

Comment: You're correct, in the context of your current code, the potential conflict I mentioned wouldn't be an issue because you're explicitly referencing the signal module by its full name (signal.SIGINT) throughout your code. I apologize for any confusion caused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just included the sleep and a print statement to just see the result

result was ok

```
$ winpty python test.py
not stopped forever
not stopped forever
pressed ctrl C
```

```
import signal
import sys
import time


def signal_abort_script(signal, frame):
    """
    Signal handler function to catch KeyboardInterrupt (Ctrl+C) and exit the script gracefully.
    """
    print("pressed ctrl C")
    sys.exit()


def main():
    # Set up the signal handler to catch KeyboardInterrupt (Ctrl+C)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_abort_script)

    # print not stopped forever
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print("not stopped forever")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: okay so i found out how it works now, the thing was that it didnt work if i ran it through my ide, but does work via console, thanks for it

Answer (score 0):

okay in the meantime i got what i wanted to achieve with a bit of help of chatgpt. Now i can start and stop the script.

```
import threading
import time
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, KeyCode

startStopButton = KeyCode(char='s')
terminateButton = KeyCode(char='\x03')

running = False
program_running = True


def start():
    global running
    running = True


def stop():
    global running
    running = False

def exit_script():
    global running, program_running
    running = False
    program_running = False


def print_hi():
    while program_running:
        if running:
            print("hi")
        time.sleep(1)  # Adjust the delay as needed


def on_press(key):
    if key == startStopButton:
        if running:
            stop()
        else:
            start()
    elif key == terminateButton:
        exit_script()
        listener.stop()


print("Press 's' to start, 'ctrl+c' to exit.")
print_hi_thread = threading.Thread(target=print_hi)
print_hi_thread.start()

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```